# How to map a component property as part of an entity's primary key?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

How can I map a component property as part of a composite primary key of an entity, using Fluent NHibernate?

For example:

```
CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Store.StoreCodeId).KeyProperty(x => x.CashRegister);
Component(x => x.Store, m =>
                {
                    m.Map(y => y.StoreCodeId);
                    m.Map(y => y.StoreName);
                }
            );
```

Is this OK?

Comment: Since both the parent class properties and the `Store` class properties refer to columns to the **same** table, your mapping should work. I don't have time to try your mapping in a concrete example, hence this comment and not an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to map column more then once. What we have to assure is that the componenet won't generate INSERT and UPDATE statements twice. If the mapping will be extended this way it should work.

```
CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Store.StoreCodeId).KeyProperty(x => x.CashRegister);
Component(x => x.Store, m =>
  {
    m.Map(y => y.StoreCodeId).Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    m.Map(y => y.StoreName);
  }
);
```

In some cases could be mapping from column change to formula, which is mostly also for selecting and ordering only.

```
CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.Store.StoreCodeId).KeyProperty(x => x.CashRegister);
Component(x => x.Store, m =>
  {
    m.Map(y => y.StoreCodeId).Formula("[StoreCodeId]").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
    m.Map(y => y.StoreName);
  }
);
```

At the end fluent will generate this xml

```
<component name="Store" >
  <property name="StoreCodeId" formula="[StoreCodeId]" insert="false" update="false" />
  <property name="StoreName" />
</component>
```

Comment: I guess that also can be used .ReadOnly(), instead of .Not.Insert().Not.Update()?

Comment: I'm fan of XML mapping, and feel that fluent is ok when more or less mimics the result which generates (xml). But I see your point, and if it could help readability and is it working... good ;)

Comment: ah, ok, thanks! I thought that those were two different things.